# Weird {display:table} behavior

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I cannot figure this one out.
When using `display:table` along with `display:table-cell`, placing an img tag in either cell1 or cell2 will force the content (the "This is a test" content for example), in the other cell to drop below the image. Is this correct? It does this across all browsers so I'm thinking this is correct, but why?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html,
        body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        div {
            border: 2px solid #000;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .table {
            display: table;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        .row {
            display: table-row;
        }
        .cell {
            display: table-cell;
            width: 50%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="table">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="cell1" class="cell">
                <h1>This is a test</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="cell2" class="cell">
                <img src="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why in the world would you do it this way instead of just using tables?

Comment: @bern can you bother to post some screenshots or something that will provide more information

Comment: giving your `.cell` class a `vertical-align: top;` seems to fix it.

Comment: @Dave: This is how you would use a table-based layout without using semantically-incorrect tables.

Comment: @jnpcl - aren't they semantically incorrect because they define the look in HTML instead of just the data?  If so, then doing it this way is incorrect too for the exact same reason imo.

Comment: @Dave The div's are defining regions in the web page. the css is styling the divs into a two column layout. There is no diffrence between wrapping content and floating it or wrapping it and dividing up into controlled regions.

Comment: @bern @jnpcl - you're correct - It seems kinda crazy, but only because I've never seen it done that way before - but - very cool - I may do it that way in the future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm. `vertical-align: top` in the table-cell.

Workin example: [at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vT4cR/)

Answer (score 0):

This is because inserting an image into the div, takes your layout out of the natural flow of the layout.

I would suggest just using tables, or if not the case use float, and create it that way.

Answer (score 0):

set `style="verticle-align:top"` for your "cell" divs